# Is the sum of hashes a suitable hash for sets?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Let $H: X \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^b$ denote a cryptographically secure, $b$-bits hash function on a set $X$. Let $H^*: \mathbb{P}(X) \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^b$ be a function on the power set of $X$ defined by
\begin{equation}
H^*(\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}) = \sum_i H(x_i)
\end{equation}
where the sum is intended as wrapping addition over $b$-bit integers.

I am wondering if $H^*$ is cryptographically secure on $\mathbb{P}(X)$.

I easily see that other aggregation mechanisms (such as XOR-ing all hashes together) are easily prone to collisions. I also see how, if the same element of $X$ could appear multiple times in the collection being hashed, one could build a collision by simple integer division. But, if all the elements of $X$ being hashed are distinct, I can’t easily see an attack on this construction.

Comment: How does the sum of hashes exactly works? My reading of the question is it's modulo $2^b$, but an answer mentions modulo $2^b-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what other people say, this is actually (when modified slightly) fine.
You seem interested in the problem of *homomorphic hashing*.
Note that while fully homomorphic encryption refers to being (ring)-homomorphic, i.e. with respect to something like $(\mathbb{F}_2, +, \times)$, homomorphic hashing refers to being homomorphic with respect to the monoid $(\mathbb{P}(X), \cup)$, i.e. precisely your notion of homomorphism.

Anyway, constructions of homomorphic hashes have been known for quite a while.
See [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/227.pdf) for a semi-recent discussion of things.
Something *almost exactly* like your proposal actually *is* secure (it is called "LtHash", and dates back to the 90s).
The "trick" here is that one hashes onto $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ for $n$ large.
One can then reduce the collision resistance of the hash to a standard lattice problem (the Short Integer Solution problem), which (when appropriately parameterized) is thought to be hard.
Note that the setting of $n = 1$ (your actual case) is likely insecure though, at least without setting $q$ to be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *I misinterpreted the algebraic domain, but the answer can be adapted, see below.*

*The complexities exhibited are exponential, but reduced, and in applications such as hash functions, LWE, LPN where similar structures are used, these reduced complexities are of interest.*

$H^\star$ is definitely insecure. Like most attacks on hash functions you will generate random inputs looking for collisions. Here let's consider addition modulo
$2^b-1,$ as you suggest.

If $n$ is small compared to $2^b,$ there are still shortcuts which reduce the complexity substantially. Here is an attack finding a collision on such a function. Given some desired hash output $H_0,$
assume we have a random set of $v=2^{b/n}$ hashes, of the form
$$H^\star(\{x_{1,i},\ldots,x_{n,i}\}),\quad i=1,\ldots,v\quad(1).$$
Since here are $v^n=2^b$ possible $n-$sums of the form (1) these sums we have assembled will  will hit your $H_0$  with constant probability since the hash target space has size $2^{b}.$

*Explanation:* We have a finite domain, and balls in bins process with $2^b$ possible inputs.

If $n=2$ this would essentially be the birthday problem with complexity $O(2^{b/2}).$ By reduction to the case when $n=2^s$ is a power of 2, Wagner [gave](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2002/24420288/24420288.pdf) an $$O(2^{b/(1+s)}=O(2^{b/(1+\lceil \log  n\rceil)})$$ recursive solution for the case of XOR but this can be adapted to any finite group, including addition modulo $2^b-1.$ See also chapter 8 of the book *Algorithmic Cryptanalysis* by Antoine Joux.

Comment: You state that $H^*$ is definitely insecure, however the solutions you give take time exponential in $b$

Comment: Forgive me, I’m having trouble navigating this answer. If I understand correctly, you’re proposing to generate a v x n matrix of random elements, then observe that if you pick one element from each “column” you have enough combinations to fill the hash space? Or am I mistaken? But.. how do you select the correct combination?

Comment: Also I’m having a bit of trouble with the value of v. First you propose to set it to 2^(b/n), then you mention n =2^v which would imply v = log2(n). What am I missing?

Comment: Finally, the result that you linked mentions XORs, but I’m probably too inexperienced to see the relationship that result bears with my question, which concerns sums modulo 2^b.  Sorry I am so easily confused!

Comment: you brute force to find the correct combination, like all collision attacks.

Comment: Of course, of course, but it is not immediate to me how the sum step makes this faster than a simple birthday attack. Let’s assume for simplicity H0 = 0. Every time I compute H* I either find something that complements a previous output I found, or I save it and carry on. This in my mind takes around 2^(b/2) steps. I understand that there is a faster solution, but I am not getting how it works.

Comment: I’ll try to read through the link you sent and wrap my head around it!

Comment: Gaussian elimination won't works in this case, because it finds a solution which coefficients are in the ring of the elements of the matrix, but the problem statement restricts coefficients of the solution to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

As a illustration that $H^*$ is sizably less secure than a $b$-bit hash, I give a collision attack with $\mathcal O(2^{b/3})$ hashes and $\mathcal O(b\,2^{b/3})$ memory. For simplicity, assume $b$ is a multiple of $3$, and the addition in the computation of $H^*$ is carried modulo $2^b$.

- Choose an easily computable function $X(i)$ mapping integers $i$ to $x_i\in X$; we'll note $H_i$ for $H(X(i))$.
- Set a table $T$ to empty, that will holds pairs $(i,H_i)$ indexed for search according to key $H_i\bmod2^{b/3}$.
- Set a table $U$ to empty, that will holds triplets $(i,j,(H_i+H_j\bmod2^b)/2^{b/3})$ such that $H_i+H_j\bmod2^{b/3}=0$, indexed to detect triplets with the same third element.
- For increasing $i$

  - compute $H_i$
  - search for an $H_j$ already in table $T$ with key $(-H_i)\bmod2^{b/3}$
  - If none is found, enter $(i,H_i)$ in table $T$ (to conserve memory at the expense of a little more hashes: except if the number of entries with key $H_i\bmod2^{b/3}$ is already some small threshold, e.g. 3)
  - Otherwise, remove $(j,H_j)$ from table $T$ and enter $(i,j,(H_i+H_j\bmod2^b)/2^{b/3})$ in table $U$, while testing for collision with an entry already in $U$ having the same third element. In that exceptional case we have $H^*(\{X(i),X(j)\})$ colliding with that earlier and different $H^*(\{X(i'),X(j')\})$ already in $U$, and stop with that collision.

Each new entry in $U$ costs a small constant number of hashes, and since the value we want to collide is $2b/3$-bit, we need $\mathcal O(2^{b/3})$ hashes.

As the saying [attributed to the NSA by Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/08/new_attack_on_a_1.html) goes: *Attacks only get better; they never get worse*, and I see room for improvement. Independently, the attack can be adapted to other moduli (like $2^b-1$ or the largest $b$-bit prime) at moderate extra cost.